# spring-data-elasticsearch - None of the configured nodes are available

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I use the spring-data-elasticsearch with the version of 3.0.0  there has been a problem in use process, sometimes successfully, sometimes will report the error

None of the configured nodes are available: [
{#transport#-1} {S0DLwdVZRk-Osl4KgxM91A} {127.0.0.1} {127.0.0.1:9300}

Elasticsearch is version 5.4.0.

My spring configuration file is

```
 <elasticsearch:repositories base-package="com.ai.notify.es.repository"/>

 <elasticsearch:transport-client id="client" cluster-nodes="127.0.0.1:9300" 
 cluster-name="my-message" />

 <bean name="elasticsearchTemplate" 
    class="org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="client" ref="client"/>
 </bean>
```

and my elasticsearch.yml is

```
cluster.name: my-message
client.transport.ignore_cluster_name: true
http.cors.enabled: true

 http.cors.allow-origin: "*"

 client.transport.sniff: true
```

This is because what causes.

This error does not appear frequently, but occasionally

Comment: Just to be sure: You are using 3.0.0 M4 (so the pre release)?

Comment: 3.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT this version.

Answer (score 0):

spring-data-elastic 3.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT uses version 5.5.0 of the elastic search client library. See [pom.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/pom.xml#L22). So your elastic search server version must be ***exactly*** 5.5.0. Not even 5.5.1 or 5.5.2 or 5.5.3 or 5.5.4 etc. Exactly 5.5.0.